# Google Analytics: How can I see the IP addresses of those visiting my site?

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, what's the code I need to add to my website so I can log peoples IP addresses (v4/v6)? Is there any way to get their MACs as well?  Thanks!

Comment: I think Google Analytics deliberately *doesn’t* provide user IP information to preserve privacy, IIRC. MAC is a hardware address that wouldn’t be readable over HTTP unless you’re in the same network segment as the client (GA will *not* be; and would be a privacy nightmare if advertisers could get a hold of it). Can you expand on *why* you need this data? The community may be able to suggest workarounds with more contextual information.

Comment: In the event someone tries to perform an action against my website, I'd like to at least have an IP address of the person...

Comment: Unfortunately this isn’t a use case for Google Analytics. You can configure your site’s backend code to get the requestor’s IP address and store it in a database or log files (as most all other web sites/services do). However, IP addresses are mutable and generally don’t map back to any particular “*person*”, so its applications as a unique identifier are somewhat limited and/or unreliable. You should consider editing your question to add more specific context, as “an action” is particularly broad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Comment: @DalmTo "I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related" - it appears that code was just suggested...

Answer (score 1):

In Google Tag Manager navigate to `Tags > New > Custom HTML` and paste in the following script:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    dataLayer.push({"event":"ipEvent","ipAddress" : json.ip});  
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

You have to create a **custom dimension** in Google Analytics and a DataLayer Variable called `ipAddress` as its value in relative field in GTM.

**Note**: the Google Analytics TOS does not allow to send PII to the platform, so it is at your own risk (the danger is account closure and loss of all data).

Comment: Will give it a shot - thank you Michele! Or should I say "Grazie!"